# Autodesk Forge Viewer: pdf calibration

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

why do I measure different values if I calibrate the pdf on and off the drawing lines

[calibration on lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uP7X.png)

[measure after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLgEz.jpg)

[calibration outside lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omeOj.jpg)

[measure after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gpxm.jpg)

[pdf file](https://file.io/ubSbjrLSlGGt)

Thanks for more information

I expected same measure value

Answer (score 0):

We would need some more details to be able to help:

- the original PDF (the link you provided says the resource has been deleted)
- how exactly are you loading the PDF, i.e., are you loading it directly to the viewer using the `Autodesk.PDF` extension, or are you translating it using the Model Derivative service?
- what version of the viewer are you using, and how exactly are you loading the model into it?

If this were a 2D drawing, one possible explanation would be *viewports*. Basically, the viewer supports drawings with viewports that can have varying scales, so calibrating inside and outside of these viewports could yield different scales, and therefore different measurements.